# Critique this proof on compactness.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-writing, compactness

Problem: Prove or disprove, the metric space $X$ containing infinitely many points with the discrete metric is compact. Write a proof in the language of sequences and covers

> **Proof**: Take $(1/n) \to 0$. Every term of $(1/n)$ is distinct, and $d(x_n, x) \nrightarrow  0$ as $n \to \infty$. Since every subsequence must also have distinct terms, then the subsequence must also satisify $d(x_{n_k}, x) \nrightarrow  0$

Comment: you just need to say something like - if $X=\{x_i | i\in I\}$ then the open cover $\{\{x_i\} | i\in I\}$ has no finite subcover ($I$ some infinite indexing set)

Comment: It looks like you're assuming that X is countably infinite.

Comment: @anonymous nope a index set does not need to be countable in general

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some notes before Brian M. Scott gives the complete run-down.

**Open cover proof**

- If $X$ is uncountable, then $\{ N_1 ( x_i) \}_{i > 1}$ will not cover $X$ (there are too many points of $X$ to be indexed by the positive integers).  Better is to say that "$\{ N_1 ( x ) \}_{x \in X}$ is a(n open) cover of $X$."  The benefits of this will come in the second point.
- Assuming compactness you have a finite subcover, which, according to your notation should be phrased by stating that there are positive integers $i_1 , \ldots , i_k$ such that $\{ N_1 (x_{i_1} ) , \ldots , N_1 (x_{i_k} ) \}$ covers $X$.  Of course, using the notational trick in my first point we can remove one level of subscript and say instead that there are $x_1 , \ldots , x_k \in X$ such that $\{ N_1 ( x_1 ) , \ldots , N_1 ( x_k ) \}$ covers $X$.
- Also note that in your notation for the finite subcover you never mention what $m$ ranges over.
- It is completely unimportant that $N_1 (x_{k+1} )$ does not belong to $\{ N_1 ( x_{i_j} ) : j \leq m \}$; all that is important is that $x_{k+1}$ does not belong to any $N_1 ( x_{i_j} )$ for $j \leq m$.
- You appear to use $m$ as both the index that the finite subcover ranges over, and also the upper bound of the index that the finite subcover ranges over.

**Sequences proof**

- <strike>I honestly have no idea what is going on with your proof.  You start with a sequence of positive reals converging to $0$, and then magically instantiate a sequence in $X$.  I'm starting to think that the underlying set of your discrete space is $\mathbb{R}$ (or something similar) which may not be the case.</strike>
- You appear to be using the same indexing of the space $X$ from the first proof.  This was very unclear to me for a while.
- I do not know what value the sequence $( 1/n )_{n =1}^\infty$ has in this proof.
- Your logical reasoning is correct (every subsequence of $(x_i)$ will have distinct terms and therefore &c.&c.&c.), however this might not satisfy someone grading a paper/exam.  Perhaps better is to say that since $d ( x_i , x_j ) = 1$ for all $i \neq j$ then no subsequence can be Cauchy (because given any subsequence $( x_{i_k} )_k$ there is no $K$ such that $d ( x_{i_k} , x_{i_\ell} ) < 1$ for all $k, \ell \geq K$) and therefore no subsequence can converge.
- The above point is contingent on "showing" that there is a sequence in $X$ consisting of pairwise distinct terms.

Comment: @sizz: I think I just figured out your sequence proof.  You are using the _same indexing_ from the first proof, correct?  I'll edit my answer presently.  (But you are correct in just needing to produce a single sequence with no converging subsequence.)

Comment: @sizz: When you speak about the sequence $( x_n )_n$ in your sequences proof does this sequence correspond to the indexing of the space $X$ from the open cover proof?  (The first line of it where you say "$\{ N_1(x_i) \}_{i \geq 1}$ be a cover for $X$.")

Comment: @sizz: Well, as I noted in the very first point of my answer, it may not be possible to enumerate $X$ (with the positive integers).  But, yes, assuming that $X$ is countably infinite the outline of the proof wouldn't change.

Comment: Maybe I should have added this "Let $x = \mathbb{R}$ and take the sequence $(x_n)$..." to make it clearly that there is some metric space and some sequence such that...etc.etc..

Comment: For the criticism on cover proof (1) i thought open cover = cover (3) so I could say $1 \leq m \leq k$ and this fixes (2) as well? (4) I am not sure what the difference is

Comment: @sizz:  (re: 2nd last comment) When you do that you lose generality (which is a _bad thing_).  Instead of showing "No infinite discrete metric space is cmpact" you only demonstrate "$\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete metric is not compact."  You should know that if a set $X$ is infinite there is a one-to-one function $\mathbb N \to X$, and that's all you need to get started with the sequences proof.

Comment: @sizz: (re: last comment) (1) If you have the convention that cover = open cover, feel free to omit "open" in this context.  (3) Yes, yes, yes. (4) In _this_ situation you are correct, because $N_1 ( x ) = \{ x \}$.  However in general (for example, showing the the the real line is not compact) you may run into the situation that $x \in \bigcup_{m=1}^k N_1 (x_m)$ even though $N_1 (x)$ is not among $N_1 (x_1) , \ldots , N_1 (x_k)$.

Comment: now I am sure my sequence proof is wrong. I'll just delete the $(1/n)$ all together because it makes no sense. (edit, it wouldn't let me type your name @Arthur)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're writing a much too complicated proof. Just note that $N_1(x) = \{x\}$ (which you do), so every singleton is an open set. Let $X$ be infinite and discrete. 
Supppose $X$ is compact, then the open cover $\{ \{x\}: x \in X \}$ has a finite subcover $\{x_1\},\{x_2\},\dots,\{x_k\}$. Then $X \subset \{x_1,\dots,x_k\}$, so this implies $X$ is finite, a contradiction.

As to a sequence proof, you want to show that $X$ is not sequentially compact. You write $\frac{1}{n}$, which need not be a point of $X$ (it's a general space), but the idea is there: pick a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ where all points are distinct, which can be done as $X$ is infinite. Suppose now that a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ converges to $x$, which means, taking $\epsilon = 1$, that for some $k \ge M$ we have $d(x_{n_k},x) < 1$, which means, by the definition of the metric that $x_{n_k} = x$ for all $k \ge M$, but this contradicts that all terms are distinct. So we have no convergent subsequence.

Comment: Oh okay I see the problem, I assumed that $X$ contain real numbers, which not need ot be true.